# Access denied when downloading MySQL binary log using "mysqlbinlog" command

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I want to download MySQL binary log from a MySQL 5.7.31 server running on Amazon RDS.

Here's the command I used to download the log.

```
mysqlbinlog \
    --read-from-remote-server \
    --host=mydb.example.com \
    --port=3306  \
    --user my_user_name \
    --password my_password \
    --raw \
    --result-file=/tmp \
    mysql-bin-changelog.455937
```

This command gives me the following error:

```
ERROR: Failed on connect: Access denied for user 'my_user_name'@'mydb.example.com' (using password: YES)
```

According to [this document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_LogAccess.Concepts.MySQL.html), user `my_user_name` must have replication slave permission to run the above command.

So I run `SHOW GRANTS FOR my_user_name;` to check the permission of the user.

`SHOW GRANTS FOR my_user_name;` returns the following texts.

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, RELOAD, PROCESS, REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER, SHOW DATABASES, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, REPLICATION SLAVE, REPLICATION CLIENT, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, CREATE USER, EVENT, TRIGGER ON *.* TO 'my_user_name'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, ALTER, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, EVENT, TRIGGER ON `database_a`.* TO 'my_user_name'@'%'
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, ALTER, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, EVENT, TRIGGER ON `database_b`.* TO 'my_user_name'@'%'
```

As you can see from the above result, I have `REPLICATION SLAVE` permission for `my_user_name`.

Why can't I download the binary log?

Is there anything wrong with my configuration?

I can connect to the MySQL database using `mysql` command with the same username and password.

So my username, password, and security group of the database must be correct.